# Get token appended by Paypal to my success URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url, paypal

I used PayPal Express Checkout and successfully get through the transaction, after pressing the 'Pay Now' button Paypal redirects me to the page I setup on my website, the problem is I need to get the `token` paypal appended on my url, how do I do that?

Here's the sample URL : `http://localhost:3000/#/buy-points/success?token=EC-7JK95123K5096113P&PayerID=RA85EAH95ZDGJ`

I want to get the value of the `token=EC-7JK95123K5096113P`

Here's what I have tried.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('buy-points.success', {
        url: '/buy-points/success/:token',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
        controller: 'successController',
        TOKEN: function  ($stateParams) {
             return $stateParams.token || "";
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since paypal is responding with a query parameter you should use `?parameter` format rather than the regular parameter parsing format.
Also you if you want to get a TOKEN object/variable injected in your controller you should include it inside the state resolve object.

You should do something like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('buy-points.success', {
        url: '/buy-points/success?token',
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
        controller: 'successController',
        resolve: {
           TOKEN: function  ($stateParams) {
             return $stateParams.token || '';
           }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Wow are you a wizard?! Thanks :)